# Is this post supporting my roof framing intended to be permanent?

Tags: framing, new-home, timber-framing

I purchased a new build last year and recently got my warranty inspection done. Both the inspector I hired before closing and the inspector I hired to do warranty inspection (different inspectors) said the rafters look sloppy (not cut to flushed) but should perform fine (first picture). Today I went to the attic to get my Halloween decoration and notice some weird vertical support. Pictures #2, #3 and #4 are the same support just different angles. I saw a few like that in the particular attic area I was at. My question is that are those support temporary that the framers were too lazy to remove? If those support elements are structural, they look so sloppy. Will they cause problems later on?

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QY2pX.jpg

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKjtE.jpg

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwcGJ.jpg

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxY9z.jpg

Comment: Where are you located? Are you in a heavy snow zone, a high wind area, or seismically active area? Is it a single story residence? What causes the angle of the joists and beam, a dormer? What is size of double joists (beam)?

Comment: Get it checked by a structural engineer.

Comment: What is the span (distance) of the roof joists that appears to be about 16” oc?

Comment: I'm in Dallas, TX, not in a heavy snow zone or high wind or seismically active area. It's single story. The angle is the roof. I'm not sure about the size of the double joists, I'll have to check later.

Comment: Those look pretty dodgy to my eye

Comment: I sure _hope_ that's a temporary support the put in while building and forgot/didn't bother to remove!

Comment: That post appears to be well-supported on a beam. It strikes me as non-standard, but I don't have any reason to think it's a problem. I'd like to see the structure from the outside to understand better.

Comment: The post standing on a seemly non-continuous piece of wood, and I wonder what is the purpose of the two triangle stiffeners attached. On the busy top, it seems to have a geometry change there with many pieces meeting and supported by the post. It could be the contractor utilized to fix some mistakes. Anyway, nothing is definitive until checked by an experienced contractor or engineer.